# Post on instagram from webpage

Tags: php, python, instagram, instagram-api

There are lot of same queries on Stackoverflow but seems no one covered this. So please go through this question.

I was wondering to post on Instagram from webpage via official API but I got to know that there is no provision to do that. Further researching on this function I got a [python script](https://github.com/lukecyca/python-instagram-upload) with which I was able to post images. Then also I got [PHP script](http://lancenewman.me/posting-a-photo-to-instagram-without-a-phone/) to do the same. But with both I need to attach my actual Instagram credentials (which seems okay because official API don't allow to post so that we can get token) and script isn't verifying the credentials.It will only let you know about wrong credentials when you try to post.

On other hand I found few websites :

- http://autogrammer.com
- http://onlypult.com
- http://buffergram.com/

which are allowing the same feature. They also need actual username and password but they are verifying them and let you know instantly if it's wrong.

I am trying to figure out that how they are doing it with (and which) third party script. If anyone know please share your experience.

**UPDATE**

Moreover I read few user's comments for python script that Instagram push user to change password because they think user's account is compromised.